# What is the difference between py-evm and pythereum?

Tags: python, ethereum

I usually use geth or parity client but trying to use pythereum for vyper implementation.

But looks like two types of ethereum clients using python implementation which are :

https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum

https://github.com/ethereum/py-evm

Also, there is another python client called pyethapp too. 
(https://github.com/ethereum/pyethapp)

So can anybody teach me the differences and which situation should I use which?

Comment: UPDATE : Here is the video from devcon3, explaining the difference between these two: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5bOnMKQUvI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

py-evm is the one actively developed and supported. Note that it's still in pre-alpha state. It's not ready for production use.

Comment: Thank you carver for the answer. So pyethereum is not supported?

Comment: Some people still contribute to `pyethereum` because they have legacy dependencies, but you are correct, there isn't much support. It is considered deprecated, and will be phased out soon.

Comment: Thank you carver!